# Difference between Strings added directly and with references

Tags: java, string, string-pool

I came across a question asking the output of the below:

```
    String s1 = "String 1";
    String s2 = "String 2";

    String s3 = s1 + s2;
    String s4 = "String 1" + "String 2";

    System.out.println(s3==s4);
```

Output - `false`

Now, since the strings are not created using new operator, so the objects are created in the string pool, so as per my understanding `s1 + s2` and `"String 1" + "String 2"` should be equal, and `s3==s4` should be `true`.

But it is not happening in real. Can any one please explain this?

Comment: See which of them equals the result of the `#intern` call

Answer (score 4):

[The concatenation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) is happening at runtime, unless both operands are compile-time constant expressions.

Put a `final` modifier before s1 and s2, and the result will be true, because the compiler will simply replace

```
String s3 = s1 + s2;
```

by

```
String s3 = "String 1String 2";
```

If you don't, a new String is created at runtime, by appending both strings to a StringBuilder and getting the result.

Note that, although that is interesting from an intellectual point of view, in practice, you shouldn't care about that performance optimization, and always compare Strings with `equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

This line compare memory addresses of two strings. Because of both are separate objects and output will be false.

```
s3==s4
```

You need to compare using `equals()`

```
System.out.println(s3.equals(s4));
```

`equals()` is compare value of object not address.